# If input field is empty, clear other fields (else if condition)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 3 inputs. When input 2 is changed by the user, if it's empty then the 1st and 3rd inputs should also be set to empty. However, the function I wrote to handle this never sets the values of inputs 1 and 3 to empty when input 2 is cleared.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").valueAsNumber;
    if (document.getElementById("input1").value === "input1") {
        document.getElementById("input1").readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("input3").readOnly = true;
    } else if (document.getElementById("input2").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input3").value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="input1">
<input type="number" id="input2" onchange="myfunction()">
<input type="email" id="input3" value="input3">
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? And what are you aiming to achieve (in detail)?

Comment: You could add an event listener and check the value of input 2

Comment: Avoid using `"keyup"` events if you need the `value`. You could copy/paste values, remember? In such case the key event will not be triggered. Use `"input"` instead.  Also, stop using inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use addEventListener() instead.

Comment: `<script>` should be placed right **before** the closing `</body>` tag - not after it.

Comment: @DBS What i'm trying to do is during typing in input 2, the code will check the value of input 1 with the if condition but if the user cleared input 2 I need the code to clear input 1 and 3 as well

Comment: In that if-condition of your code, you do not check the value of input1. You assign a value to it! Use the `===` operator instead of `=`.

Comment: @lupz, please see the updated question

Comment: The rewrite (that converted the sample to a live snippet) shows a clearer expression of the issue. However, the behavior is still under-specified. What are all the conditions for clearing the inputs? The sample function only clears input 1 and 3 if input 1 doesn't have the value 'input1'. Is that what's supposed to happen, or is the clearing supposed to depend solely on the value of input 2?  What, exactly, are the desired & actual behaviors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have provided solution either of one will suits your case I believe

The Html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2" value = "in" 
    onchange="myfunction(this.value)">
<input type="email" id="input3" value="input3">
</body>
```

1st solution, this will remove values in input1 and 3 if input 2 is cleared, this happens while typing.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('input2').addEventListener('input', function() {
console.log(this.value);
if (this.value == ""){
    document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input3").value = "";  
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

2nd Solution, this clears input 1 and 3 , once the input 2 is cleared and hit enter button.

```
<script>
function myfunction(val) {

if (val == ""){
    document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input3").value = "";
}
console.log(val);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Hope this what you are expecting for, if not feel free to comment. Thanks

Ps: Just now saw your updated question, if you are updating input 2, instead checking empty , you can change the condition as if there is any change in input val you can empty other two. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

your if statement is wrong, the condition always evaluates to true, you need to use == or === in the if condition.

> if (document.getElementById("input1").value == "input1") {

instead of

> if (document.getElementById("input1").value = "input1") {

Also I would use **onchange** to run the function everytime the value chanes or **onblur** to run the function only when the input 2 loses focus. **onkeyup** is not called if you use the mouse to change the value using the arrows.

Comment: please see the updated question